# How MySQL Group Replication get primary node ip address

Tags: mysql, replication

According to MYSQL 5.7 Reference Manual :

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-replication-find-primary.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-replication-monitoring.html

We can use the sql below to find the primary-node's hostname when group replication is deployed in single-mode :

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM performance_schema.replication_group_members WHERE MEMBER_ID = (SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE FROM performance_schema.global_status WHERE VARIABLE_NAME= 'group_replication_primary_member');
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| CHANNEL_NAME              | MEMBER_ID                            | MEMBER_HOST | MEMBER_PORT | MEMBER_STATE |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| group_replication_applier | 9176f4d3-c7f6-11e6-bcf7-fa163ee40410 | myhost      |       24801 | ONLINE       |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

the question is : **How to get ip address instead of hostname ?**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get any ipaddress of the hostnames. If you are connecting to some host then you know the ipaddress of that hostname. Here is the [mailing list](https://lists.mysql.com/mysql/224556) that is on mysql forum that would be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, We can use the property named `report_host` to point to our ip address, eg:

In my own machine, I deploy three node(s1,s2,s3) to form one replication group, in all `my.cnf`, define it (`10.202.7.88` is my ip address):

```
report_host=10.202.7.88
```

then restart all node and re-config three node to form the replication group, then query :

```
mysql> select * from performance_schema.replication_group_members;
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| CHANNEL_NAME              | MEMBER_ID                            | MEMBER_HOST | MEMBER_PORT | MEMBER_STATE |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| group_replication_applier | 933a5345-d321-11e6-b971-fa163ee40410 | 10.202.7.88 |       24801 | ONLINE       |
| group_replication_applier | 9abe6249-d321-11e6-bb5c-fa163ee40410 | 10.202.7.88 |       24802 | ONLINE       |
| group_replication_applier | a1c89c34-d321-11e6-bbbc-fa163ee40410 | 10.202.7.88 |       24803 | ONLINE       |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and then we can use the sql we memtion above to get the primary node ip address:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM performance_schema.replication_group_members WHERE MEMBER_ID = (SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE FROM performance_schema.global_status WHERE VARIABLE_NAME= 'group_replication_primary_member');
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| CHANNEL_NAME              | MEMBER_ID                            | MEMBER_HOST | MEMBER_PORT | MEMBER_STATE |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| group_replication_applier | 933a5345-d321-11e6-b971-fa163ee40410 | 10.202.7.88 |       24801 | ONLINE       |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```